# iOS create object

Tags: objective-c, ios, object

I want to create an object called Note . Then I want to assign some values to it's fields and display them in the console to verify that all of this works properly.

```
       Note.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Note : NSObject
{
    NSNumber *position;
    NSString *syllable;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSNumber *position;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *syllable;
@end

    Note.m

#import "Note.h"

@implementation Note
@dynamic position;
@dynamic syllable;
@end
```

After this , in another class I want to assign some values to the fields .

```
-(void) configNote:(Note*)not
{
    not = [Note alloc];
    [not setPosition:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
    [not setSyllable:@"Twin-"];
}


.....
 Note *note;

 [self configNote:note];

 NSLog(@" pos : %d syl : %@ ",[[note position] integerValue],[note syllable]);
```

I tried to use `@synthesize` instead of `@dynamic` but still nothing changes . The reason of the error is : `-[Note setPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x733d060`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`init` your note and use custom init method to initialize ivars and change dynamic to synthesize
and for better use this init to initialize your varibales

```
- (id)initWithPosition:(NSNumber*)pos andSyllable:(NSString*)syl {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.position = pos;
        self.syllable= syl;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Basically correct, though there isn't a need to override -init. It's fine to accept the default values of nil for the properties, unless the problem domain forbids this.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is quite basic and fundamental you might want to check out this [Tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) on cocoadevcentral. It's very well done and teaches you some of the basics when dealing with objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARC, try `"strong"` instead of `"retain"`.

Comment: change dynamic to synthesize anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are passing the Note object pointer to `configNote:` by value rather than by reference. Inside of `configNote:` when you set `not` to a newly allocated Note object, you are actually setting the local variable `not` to that value. What your `NSLog` call outside of your `configNote:` object actually receives is original `note` value prior to the call to `configObject:`.

To get what I believe you desire, either more the Note object allocation outside of the `configObject:` method, or pass the Note object pointer to `configObject:` by reference.